# Some doubts about DynaList plugin in Typo3

Tags: content-management-system, typo3

I am pretty new in Typo3 world (I came frome Joomla and WordPress) and I have a problem to understand the meaning of **Dyna List** plugin and, eventually, how to use it.

For example I know that this page use **Dyna List** plugin to show a list of publications: http://www.fao.org/investment/investment-policy/publications/en/

The question is: where **Dyna List plugin take this publications list?**

In its configuration I can see that: **Dyna List ---> Records ---> Select** execute a query:

```
tt_news.*,
ms.description as status_desc
```

Reading on the Typo3 documentation seems to me that **tt_news** is a Typo3 table where the news\articles are stored, is it true?

So what exactly means the previos query? It means that the previous publications in the publications list are stored as news\articles? Can you explain me in the detail the meaning of the previous query?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

The extension does not have a documentation. You can only contact the person that implementat the extension into your installation or the author of the extension.
Alternatively, you can take a look into the code or hire someone to do it for you.